# Nhibernate, sequence and version problems

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following situation on my oracle db:

When a new record need to be insert, the pk field is generated by sequence, and thats working fine.

I got another field, lets call him A, not the pk, that needs to get his value from another sequence, I also got another column that needs to get the same value as the A field got, on some cases, and on other cases not.

Another field I got called B is defined as a version column, on some cases I need to copy this value to another field.

All of this logic is simple to implement, but I wanna know how can I do all this stuff on a single insert command where is the best place to intercept the insert command, whats recommended on this special cases?

Answer (score 0):

Implement an IInterceptor, or if you want to do it the dirty way: update those columns in a trigger and map your fields as Generated="Always" (or Insert)